# How do I check if something is a type of enum without bothering about the associated value?

Tags: rust, discriminated-union

I have:

```rust
enum Instruction {
    Noop,
    Addx(isize),
}
```

Then this:

```
if self.current_instruction == Instruction::Addx {}
```

does not work. Why? I don't care about what's in the Addx, I only want to do something if the current instruction is an Addx.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this works:

```
if let Instruction::Addx(_) = self.current_instruction {}
```